# print array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing

I need to print a two-dimensional array etc:

```
var myArray = [
[0,1,2,0],
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
];
```

And make the output appear exactly how the array is:

etc

```
alert(myArray);
```

Will display:

```
var myArray = [
[0,1,2,0],
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
[0,1,2,0]
];
```

Comment: if it is in a script tag, just set the following styling attribute to the script: `display:block;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```
JSON.stringify(myArray,null,'\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like PHP's `printr()` - this is not part of standard JS, but tons of libraries will rovide you with that functionality. Start googling with a JSON encoder.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('var myArray = [\n' + myArray.join("\n") + '\n];')
```